# Qual è il senso di "polso" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Il primo di noi che osò parlare alla cartolaia «francese» (con scarso esito, suppongo) fu il ripetente Biagi. Aveva un anno, un anno e mezzo più di noi, era tarchiato e peloso, **con grossi polsi sempre vanamente inseguiti dalle maniche**.

Sto cercando di capire il significato dell'ultima frase di questo brano. 
Il mio dubbio è se "polso" qui si riferisce alla parte terminale della manica oppure alla parte del corpo giusto sopra la mano. Tendo a pensare che il significato sia quest'ultimo, ma non ne sono sicura. La frase vuol dire che, essendo Biagi così corpulento, le maniche sempre gli andavano corte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credo proprio di sì anche perché, per definizione, il "polso" (nell'altra accezione) è sempre inseguito dalla manica e quindi non sarebbe necessario sottolineare questo aspetto, soprattutto alla luce della precedente descrizione fisica.